# How to make testRigor press ENTER key?

Tags: web-testing, testrigor

In the software i'm testing, I need to press the enter key on my keyboard to search for some data.

I need to make testRigor press the "enter" key.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, we just have to write this:
`enter enter`

Like the documentation says:

> For enter, tab, backspace:
> `enter enter into "Notes"`

Answer (score 0):

```
type enter
```

is the easiest way to do it after you enter a data into an input